# Would using the Parallel class improve performance when copying scanline from bitmap to bitmap?

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, parallel-processing, copy

I need to copy scanlines from one byte* buffer to another byte* buffer with different strides.

To do this I'm using RtlMoveMemory :

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
private static unsafe extern void MoveMemory(void* dest, void* src, int size);
```

The normal way would be something like

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++ )
{
    MoveMemory(dst_ptr, src_ptr, stride);
    src_ptr += src_stride;
    dst_ptr += dst_stride;
}
```

My question is - would this be faster using the Parallel class ?

```
Parallel.For(0, height, (y) =>
{
    byte* src_ptr = src_base + y * src_stride;
    byte* dst_ptr = dst_base + y * dst_stride;
    MoveMemory(dst_ptr, src_ptr, line_width);
});
```

Or would this just impact performance negatively ?

Comment: What happened when you tried each one?

Comment: I shamefully have to admit I haven't been able to try, I'm in the middle of writing my ZMBV codec in C# (which might take another evening or two to get in a useful state :)) and I'm just theoretically wondering if using the Parallel class would help or hurt in this case.

Comment: I really doubt it.  There's no processing involved; I would expect a performance improvement if you were parallelizing something.  There's nothing to parallelize here, other than a copy which is already probably happening as fast as it possibly can anyway.  The Parallel class might actually slow it down.  But, the only way to know for sure is to test and measure.

Comment: That was my hunch as well but I'm not familiar enough with parallel tasks / memory handling to actually know. I figure I'll go with the "standard" way to start with unless somebody more knowledgable tells me parallelization would be useful here - or profiling tells me it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, my testing shows that copying line-by-line is faster. For example, I created an array representing a 1024 x 768 bitmap. The parallel version was 45% faster.

The parallel version is much faster when scan lines are longer. Below about 1 kilobytes, the single-threaded version is faster.

Tested with .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013. 64 bit mode. Compiled with release, and run without the debugger attached.

```
    private const int NumLines = 1024;
    private const int LineLength = 768*3;
    private const int ArraySize = NumLines*LineLength;
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    private static unsafe extern void MoveMemory(void* dest, void* src, int size);
    unsafe public void Test()
    {
        // initialize a big array to test the copy
        var source = Enumerable.Range(0, ArraySize).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
        var dest = new byte[ArraySize];

        fixed (byte* pSource = source, pDest = dest)
        {
            // test single threaded
            // do it once for the JIT
            Console.WriteLine("Testing single threaded...");
            MoveSingleThread(pSource, pDest, NumLines, LineLength);

            // Okay, time it.
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            MoveSingleThread(pSource, pDest, NumLines, LineLength);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Single threaded: {0:N0} ticks", sw.ElapsedTicks);
            var singleTicks = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            Console.WriteLine("Testing parallel");
            // do it once for JIT
            MoveParallel(pSource, pDest, NumLines, LineLength);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            MoveParallel(pSource, pDest, NumLines, LineLength);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel: {0:N0} ticks", sw.ElapsedTicks);

            var diff = sw.ElapsedTicks - singleTicks;
            var pct = (double) sw.ElapsedTicks/singleTicks;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference: {0:N0} ticks {1:P2}", diff, pct);
        }

    }

    private unsafe void MoveSingleThread(byte* source, byte* dest, int nLines, int lineLength)
    {
        var srcPtr = source;
        var dstPtr = dest;
        for (int y = 0; y < nLines; ++y)
        {
            MoveMemory(dstPtr, srcPtr, lineLength);
            srcPtr += lineLength;
            dstPtr += lineLength;
        }
    }

    unsafe void MoveParallel(byte* source, byte* dest, int nLines, int lineLength)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, nLines, (y) =>
        {
            byte* srcPtr = source + y * lineLength;
            byte* dstPtr = dest + y * lineLength;
            MoveMemory(dstPtr, srcPtr, lineLength);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before and in my experience, Parallel.For was slower when being used to copy each scanline. Instead, try a Parallel.For for sections of the image (several tens or hundreds of scanlines per thread). The "magic" number of scanlines is different based on the machine/memory/CPU, so you need to tweak it to get the optimal transfer rate.

Of course, as suggested above you should try each approach to see how it performs in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with the 'standard' way for now and try the Parallel thing later with larger chunks to see how it performs.